# How to update value of child record without using another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Have a (probably basic) SQL Question!

Considering this table

```
create TestTable( 
name [nvarchar](30) NULL,
record [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentRecord [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentID [nvarchar](10) NULL)

insert into TestTable
values ('Child_A', '111', '000', NULL),
('Child_B', '222', '000', NULL),
('Parent_1, '000', NULL, 'xyz'),
('Child_C', '333', '999', NULL),
('Parent_2', '999', NULL, 'qrs')
```

Child_A and Child_B are related to Parent_1 through the parentString. The parentID of Parent_1 is "xyz". I want the parentID of Child_A and Child_B to also be "xyz" (currently it's null). And similarly for Child_C and Parent_2.

How can I do this without making use of another table? For example, I was able to achieve this with another table as follows:

```
create Helper(
record [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentRecord [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentID [nvarchar](10) NULL)

insert into helper
select record, parentString, parentID from TestTable
where parentID is not null

update tt
set tt.parentID = h.parentID
from TestTable tt, helper h,
where tt.parentString = h.record
and tt.parentString is not null
```

So this works, but I have to create another table to do so. Is there a way to achieve my goal without the use of another table? Thanks!

Comment: Your design is wrong, you should only link a child to a parent via the record id, not the name as well. But can just join your table back on itself for your update - no need for another table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a self-join using `apply()` and an `updatable CTE`

```
with u as (
    select * 
    from TestTable t
    cross apply (
        select parentId NewParent
        from TestTable t2
        where t2.record=t.parentrecord
    )p
)

update u set parentId=newParent
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join a subquery and then update

```
create TABLE TestTable( 
name [nvarchar](30) NULL,
record [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentRecord [nvarchar](10) NULL,
parentID [nvarchar](10) NULL);
GO

insert into TestTable
values ('Child_A', '111', '000', NULL),
('Child_B', '222', '000', NULL),
('Parent_1', '000', NULL, 'xyz'),
('Child_C', '333', '999', NULL),
('Parent_2', '999', NULL, 'qrs')
GO
```

```
5 rows affected
```

```
UPDATE TestTable
SET TestTable.parentID = h.parentID
FROM TestTable tt
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TestTable where parentID is not null) h
ON tt.parentRecord = h.record
and tt.parentRecord is not null
GO

SELECT * FROM TestTable
GO
```

```
name     | record | parentRecord | parentID
:------- | :----- | :----------- | :-------
Child_A  | 111    | 000          | xyz     
Child_B  | 222    | 000          | xyz     
Parent_1 | 000    | null         | xyz     
Child_C  | 333    | 999          | qrs     
Parent_2 | 999    | null         | qrs
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e76f22f51f659f66199548615de0de4b)*